# jax-rs jersey servlet not found

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, servlets, jersey

I'm trying to get this tutorial to work
https://avaldes.com/file-upload-example-using-restful-web-service-with-jax-rs-and-jersey/comment-page-1/#comment-319

This looks like an eclipse project.  I downloaded it and imported it into eclipse.  How to run it?  There was no "run on server" or "run as web page".  The only options available was "run as application" and "run as applet", neither of which this is.  My project tree looks just like theirs except for JRE System Library, Pivotal tc Server, and Web App Libraries.  I gave up.

Next I went to NetBeans and imported the eclipse project.  Clicked green Run button and up popped the web page, running on tomcat. But the url showed http://localhost:8084/, not localhost:8084/RestfulFileUploadExample.

I clicked the Browse... button and grabbed a file.  Then clicked Upload File button.  It put the following url into the browser: http://localhost:8084/RestfulFileUploadExample/rest/files/upload but got "The requested resource is not available.  Now what?

Answer (score 0):

there are issue in web.xml file check this file again it should be on WEB-INF folder and then check mapping of class file is proper or not. you can use this bellow code :-

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:Beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.demo.services</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Everything looks correct to me.  Anyway, I found a different way to do it that actually works.  See https://www.geekmj.org/jersey/jax-rs-multiple-files-upload-example-408/